# Javascript jQuery plugin DataTables de-select element

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I'm using javascript datatable and I'm trying to de-select my selected rows.

I managed to do this code but this only removes the selected appearance (css) and the rows stay selected.

As you can see they are not selected but there are 2 selected rows.

[image]

How do I completely remove the selected rows?

```
//de-select selected rows
table.rows('.selected').nodes().to$().removeClass('selected');
```

Comment: How it is identifying as `selected`? There might be some array or some value apart from css

Comment: I'm using this: https://datatables.net/examples/api/select_single_row.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use DataTables [deselect()](https://datatables.net/reference/api/rows().deselect()) method to deselect rows found by the row-selector

So for example

```
//de-select selected rows
table.rows('.selected').deselect();
```